# Corda 4.0 AWS Node Deployment Issue

Tags: linux, docker, networking, amazon-ec2, corda

I have run into issue with running JVM processes on Docker after upgrading library due to development reasons to new version (Corda 4), as up to now I was setting the program (node) running in a Docker container to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) while running in host mode on AWS EC2, which would bind it to all network interfaces, listening on all interfaces and using that forward.

Now in latest, 4, they have coded in https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/061db8b1a1ac1fa9f1a063caf7ce4f009aa283db/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/internal/Node.kt#L322 preventing this feature.

This in conjunction with https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html

> In practice the ArtemisMQ messaging services bind to all local addresses on the specified port. However, note that the host is the included as the advertised entry in the network map. As a result the value listed here must be externally accessible when running nodes across a cluster of machines. If the provided host is unreachable, the node will try to auto-discover its public one.

This results in having to specify the public IP in the node configuration, which it then tries to bind to, but it cannot as EC2 does not have the public ip visible as a direct network interface, just an internal routing interface(NIC) which at a later stage in their stack gets translated to public IP.

AWS EC2 instance ifconfig:

```
 br-9121696521bd Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:56:7C:6A:27
      inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
 ...
 docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:78:C3:69:1B
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
 ...
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:5F:BE:63:67:82
      inet addr:10.0.0.56  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
 ...
 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
 ...
 veth0c214d6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BE:2A:29:08:94:B3
      inet6 addr: fe80::bc2a:29ff:fe08:94b3/64 Scope:Link
 ...
 veth2b54799 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:81:E9:01:91:10
      inet6 addr: fe80::6481:e9ff:fe01:9110/64 Scope:Link
 ...
 veth60fffa5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7A:FE:10:33:A9:80
      inet6 addr: fe80::78fe:10ff:fe33:a980/64 Scope:Link
 ...
 vethe4f9a9a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr EE:C7:CB:C8:25:85
      inet6 addr: fe80::ecc7:cbff:fec8:2585/64 Scope:Link
```

Outcome:

1. Corda now forces me to set in node.conf p2pAddress which is then published to NMS, and used by other nodes to communicate with it.
2. I cannot set EC2 public IP as Corda attempts to "bind" to the NIC with that hostname, which is not exposed directly to EC2
3. I cannot set it to 0.0.0.0 to make it bind to all nics and listen to all incoming routes as they hardcoded in core Node.kt to stop node if 0.0.0.0 provided
4. I can only set to ip visible in container/host which are not visible outside -> node unreachable
5. I have looked at trying to fool Docker network stack into representing its local ip to that of the external ip as it is virtual network layer, but it only provides subnetting ability to existing NIC (10.0.x.x IP) or in loopback ip ranges ( 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x or 172.x.x.x)
6. This post [Running corda nodes in different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935523/running-corda-nodes-in-different-machines) also exemplifies precisely my issue and the solution i came to as well, which they closed off in 4.0

**Question/Possibilities**

Option 1 (AWS/Docker):

Spoof Public IP to be visible in EC2 as actual NIC IP via Docker IPAM/Pipeworks or Linux specific via IP masquerading with a virtual interface ?

Option 2(Corda specific):

Change configuration to somehow accept 0.0.0.0 or make detectPublicIp be more inteligent and use NMS to discover its own IP. I expected it to have this intelligence but I later discovered it just looks on at available NIC's. It fails with AMQ224000 error.

From my understanding **Corda 4.0 is unable** to run on public cloud providers (Azure/AWS/GC) due to it requiring NIC with Public IP to be present, element which Azure/AWS/GC do not have available, could somebody from Corda team correct me if I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the internal Artemis server cannot bind as it's using(by default) the p2pAddress which now has to be a valid public one. You can override this by providing a messagingServerAddress as well. See https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html?highlight=messagingserveraddress for a bit more details.