# Corda nodes are hanging at collecting signatures,when I am performing transactions on different machines

Tags: corda

I am trying to run Example Cordapp in two different VMs. With Notary and PartyC in 1st server and PartyA and PartyB in 2nd server.

I followed the steps here, Corda nodes: how to connect two independent pc as two nodes

In the conf file of,

Notary and PartyC - I have edited the P2P address
PartyA and PartyB - I have edited the P2P address
With the above conf files, I ran the Network Bootstrapper jar in server 1 and copied the folders PartyA and PartyB in another cordapp example to server 2 and started the Notary and Parties 1 by 1 respectively in the corresponding VMs.

All nodes started succesfully and when I try to execute a IOU flow from PartyC(in server 1) to PartyB(in server2), it is pausing at Collecting counterparties signature step without proceeding further. Below is what I see in PartyC's Console,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2aYu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The flow getting stuck in CollectSignatureFlow means the initiating node is not able to get a response from the counterparty node.

The CollectSignatureFlow internally establishes a session with the counterparty node and shares the transaction data to get the signature.

Since you have nodes in separate machines, they are probably not able to see each other. Generally, if nodes are hosted in a separate VM, the VM's must have public IPs or must be in a network where they are able to see each other.

Comment: As I am operating on VMs for this cordapp develpoment, is there any way out to make nodes communicate and perform IOUs. Is it possible to continue working with VMs for this? Also I checked the public ip of both the VMs are also same. Will it work with same public ip/

Comment: What is  the p2p address you provided in the node.conf files? Thats the address the nodes will try to refer to each other

Comment: You need to make sure that the addresses are accessible from each VMs

Comment: In server 1,I ran deployNodes, parties were created(A,B,C and notary). Then For the p2p address in the conf files of Party A and B , I changed it to the ip address of server 2 .  Then bootstrapped the network.Then I moved Party A and B folders to server 2 . Then from both the servers I ran call workflows-kotlin/build/nodes/runnodes. They started from both the servers.But transaction getting stuck. I followed this ink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935523/running-corda-nodes-in-different-machines

Comment: The ip address of sever2 is accessible from server 1 and vice versa?

Comment: Also make sure that the ports are open

Comment: Yeah i tried  ping ipaddres in the CMD to check the ip address are accesible from both the VMs.Its working.Any other way to check?

Comment: Did you check if the ports are open ?

Comment: Yeah.ports are listening.

Comment: Well, then it has to do something with the IP addresses used. Here is a guide to run nodes on separate machines. But I think you have got the basics right. Just revalidate and figure out if the machines are reaches from each other: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines